# Parsing a sample sheet file with data in column in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, parsing

I have a file that I want parse data that are in column not by row. The format of xls file is like this:

```
PROJECT NAME    Testing
PROJECT PI  Tester
Primary Contact Name    Tester
Primary Contact Email   testing@tester.com
DATA SUBMISSION DATE    3/29/19
```

I am currently using this script,

```
def read_csv(file, json_file):
csv_rows = []
with open(file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    title = reader.fieldnames
    for row in reader:
        csv_rows.extend([{title[i]:row[title[i]] for i in range(len(title))}])
    write_json(csv_rows, json_file)
```

And it parses the data the way I want, if I set the table as:

```
PROJECT NAME    PROJECT PI    Primary Contact Name
Testing         Tester        Tester
```

I researched about this a lot, but could not find anything about it parses by column instead of by rows.

Comment: In your input file, are the two columns separated by a tab character? Also, it would be good if the sample input file had data for more than one record: it's important to know how the rows of one record are separated (if at all) from those of the next record.

Comment: @MichaelDyck thanks for the comment! since it is in excel file, they will be in different cell. Once it is saved in csv, it will probably separated by comma.

Comment: Re "Once it is saved in csv, it will probably separated by comma.": Ah, so the sample input you showed *isn't* from the csv? You need to show (a representative sample of) the csv file, because *that's* what the Python file is reading. Moreover, the sample should show data for more than one project, because it's important to see how the rows of one are separated (if at all) from the rows of the next.